# Replacing modal content after it's opened? AngularUI Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

Could someone explain how I can replace the content inside a modal once it's opened? I'm opening a modal when a specific websocket event is fired.

After that event I get status updates and I want to replace the modal content with those statuses.

My code to open a modal:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    template: r.message.description,
    windowTemplateUrl: 'modal.html',
    controller: 'ModalController',
    backdrop: true,
    size: 'lg',
    resolve: {}
});
```

modal.html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Document Reader</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" uib-modal-transclude>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

`r.message.description` is a string I get from the websocket. That's what I need to replace inside the modal.

Cheers,

Bento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for both replies, I've tried them both but in the end I've used events to bring data from one controller to another in this specific case.

In the MainController i'm doing a

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("scanFinished", r.message);
```

and in the ModalController I'm listening for the event:

```
$scope.$on("scanFinished", function(evt, data) {
    $scope.result = data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LuotDnQX1RuMKSTWy3zd?p=preview) that I've created where you can see to understand how to pass data to a modal.

Using resolve injects the map into your given `ModalController`. You can write the same in your resolve or better use `angular.copy` like how I've done(its just for clearer coding).

Try replacing your `r.message.description` with my `$scope.name`. You then call your controller (note its a function here), with an additional `item` (for which you should use dependency injection for minification of the code). This item helps you pass data to the modal, which inherits the same from your `resolve`.

Comment: I'll try to make sense of all of that :P Your plunkr works fine, I'll see if I can get my own code to work with that.

Can't I just use $rootScope to pass a variable to the ModalController?

Comment: Any idea how to integrate your plunker with my Modalservice?

http://kopy.io/UOSav


You're using $scope.open but I'm opening modals using this service.

Comment: Your [UOSav](http://kopy.io/UOSav) is a 404. I'm not using $scope.open but the inbuilt `$uibModal.open()` of `angular-ui.bootstrap` which you are using. But the more important point is instead of your template being r.message.description, it should work if you write the same in your resolve, as that will pass the same to your `modal.html` which can be evaluated there using `{{item}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach, to render static template

```
template: '<div ng-bind-html="myScopeVar"></div>',
resolve: {
    eventTemplate: function(){
       return r.message.description;
    }
}
```

and manage "myScopeVar" inside modal controller.

If it's template with angular directive, use custom directive, which will compile your template.

```
template: '<div compile-template="myScopeVar"></div>'
```

to implement compile-template directive, you should use $compile service.